# Why is the bundle always null in spite of key being present?

Tags: java, android

---

The code below is intended to pass the data, using bundle, collected on signing up in Signup.java to ViewProfile.java which displays the data. On checking for a key in the bundle, it returns true, however, the bundle is null when checked in ViewProfile.java. Help will b appreciated.

Signup.java

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    final EditText n=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText u=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    final EditText p=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    final EditText c=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    Button s=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    final Userdatabase udb=new Userdatabase(this);
    s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String name=n.getText().toString();
            String email=u.getText().toString();
            String password=p.getText().toString();
            String phone=c.getText().toString();
            boolean b=udb.insertuser(name,email,password);
            if(b==true) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Signup.this, MainActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("NAME",name);
                bundle.putString("ID",email);
                bundle.putString("PHONE",phone);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

ViewProfile.java

```
public class ViewProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

String name,username,contact,profession;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
    if(b!=null) {
        name = b.getString("NAME");
        username = b.getString("ID");
        contact = b.getString("PHONE");
        TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView17);
        TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        TextView tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView19);
        tv1.setText(name);
        tv2.setText(username);
        tv3.setText(contact);
    }
    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(ViewProfile.this,Profile.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the wrong activity in the SignUp activity:

```
    if(b==true) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Signup.this, MainActivity.class);//problem here
```

You have set the intent as MainActivity.class and sending data to MainActivity and not to ViewProfile activity.

Change to this in SignUp activity:

```
if(b==true) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Signup.this, ViewProfile.class);
```

Comment: This worked! But I want it to first go to mainactivity.java from where I select ViewProfile class. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes. Send data to Mainactivity. In MainActivity get the data and store in varialble and then send the data to ViewProfile.

Comment: Seems tedious. Just came across another utility, Singleton class.
Thank you for your help though.

Comment: ya...singleton can be used.